# Why do custom styled Google Maps (v3) not support marker animation (pin drop)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome

For example, I cannot combine the concepts of this simple example:
[link text](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations.html) with the concepts of this example: [link text](http://maps-api-tt.appspot.com/apilite/styled/styled.html), which uses the styled V3 api.

In Chrome I get an error saying that:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DROP' of undefined`

And it refers to this line of code:

```
animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
```

When I replace the javascript link reference to use the version of the API from the first example, the error goes away, but I lose the custom styling. I have not tried this in Firefox or IE.

EDIT: Link to example: [link text](http://pastebin.com/VqZAaFE4)

Comment: Do you have a link to your code that is generating the error?

Comment: Added a link to the offending code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing an external JS file that then references Google's JS file. I wasn't able to use that, it gave me the error.

I re-wrote your code using Google's JS directly:

Preview here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kai/Unh2M/embedded/result/

View source here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kai/Unh2M/

Comment: I'm not seeing where I'm referencing a local JS file, I must me mad. But it works.

Comment: Sorry, "local" was a typo; meant external. On line #9 in the link you supplied (http://pastebin.com/VqZAaFE4) - you are calling an external JS file which then calls Google's JS file in some obfuscated manner. I think that's where the original problem lies. You should always link to Google's JS directly to ensure it works + CDN cache for some visitors. Glad this solution is working for you, though!